# Recover Windows Encrypted Files

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery

Today my harddrive had some kind of mid-life crisis and got itself in a state that no amount of `dskchk`ing or "Startup Recovery"ing could resolve, so I attached another disk, installed windows on that and recovered the files from the old disk, all well and good.

The problem is there's one directory I had encrypted, and of course the contents of the recovered files are gibberish.  Is it possible, since I have full access to the disk, and know the account password it was encrypted with, I may still be able to decrypt it somehow?

Edit: I do not have explicit backups of the keys, I am hoping that Windows stores them somewhere by default.

Comment: If you backed up the key, yes.

Comment: Updated post, don't have an explicit backup unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I used http://www.diskinternals.com/efs-recovery/ which was quick and painless: found the encrypted files/authentication data with a scan of the drive, requested password for the account, and decrypted the files.

I was even able to use the free version as it allows preview, and the files I was recovering were plain-text.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a [utility](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Decrypting-Decoding/EFS-Key.shtml) for this. I suspect the working version will cost you.